# Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /usr/lib/python2.7/ensurepip/_bundled/pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl: no space left on device

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2, pip

I was trying to run my container orchestrator code, which is a flask application on an EC2 instance.

When i ran my orchestrator.py, I get the aforementioned error.

Why is this happening and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're out of disk space.  The easiest solution is to spin up a new machine with more space.  Otherwise, if that's not a simple solution, check [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-modify-volume.html) to help you resize.  But realize that that assumes that you're using EBS, not local storage.

**If** you're using [EBS](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) you can use the AWS cli, and resize with something like:

```
aws ec2 modify-volume --size 256 --volume-id vol-11111111111111111
```

which would change your disk to 256GB.  Note that there are further steps needed to then actually use that space.